# What's the error in concatenation in below code?

Tags: php, syntax-error, concatenation

What's the error in below code:
I'm getting the error as below:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in pdf_test_question_paper.php on line 38

```
$header_html = '<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:12px; font-family:verdana;">
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://www.example.com/upload_media/coaching/logo/display/".$coaching_details['coach_inst_logo_name']." width="198"></td>
  <td>
    <h2 style="margin:0;padding:0;">Jumbo Exam Easing your Exam Preparation</h2>
    <span>$coaching_address</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><hr style="background-color: #000000;height:1px;border:1px;"/></td></tr>
</table>';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: What's line 38? I see too many questions like this. Take the time to learn how to [interpret errors and fix your code](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/05/fixing-php-errors/).

Answer (score 2):

When you wrap your string in single quotes, you're using literal values. That means `$coaching_address` will never be evaluated. You should use a [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) instead for this amount of code:

```
$header_html = <<<EOD
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:12px; font-family:verdana;">
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://www.xyz.com/upload_media/coaching/logo/display/$coaching_details['coach_inst_logo_name']" width="198"></td>
  <td>
    <h2 style="margin:0;padding:0;">Zimma Exam Easing your Exam Preparation</h2>
    <span>$coaching_address</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><hr style="background-color: #000000;height:1px;border:1px;"/></td></tr>
</table>
EOD;
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the heredoc syntax

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - that's still going to result in weirdness - inside the image tag there is another variable which now has an erroneous ". ." around it!

Comment: @LiamWiltshire I caught and fixed that seconds before your comment

Answer (score 0):

please use the correct quotation in case of string concaternation:

```
$header_html = '<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:12px; font-family:verdana;">
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://www.example.com/upload_media/coaching/logo/display/'.$coaching_details['coach_inst_logo_name'].' width="198"></td>
  <td>
    <h2 style="margin:0;padding:0;">Jumbo Easing your Exam Preparation</h2>
    <span>'.$coaching_address.'</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><hr style="background-color: #000000;height:1px;border:1px;"/></td></tr>
</table>';
```

Comment: just note there is a second variable in the code:
 <span>$coaching_address</span>
For completness, this should be taken out of quotes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You start your string using single quotes, however you are trying to break out of the quotes using a double quote.

The correct code is:

```
$header_html = '<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:12px; font-family:verdana;">
<tr>
  <td><img src="http://www.example.com/upload_media/coaching/logo/display/'.$coaching_details['coach_inst_logo_name'].' width="198"></td>
  <td>
    <h2 style="margin:0;padding:0;">Jumbo Easing your Exam Preparation</h2>
    <span>'.$coaching_address.'</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><hr style="background-color: #000000;height:1px;border:1px;"/></td></tr>
</table>';
```